Image won't load in webpack build
slider.js
...
const initialize = (pImages) => {
  pImages.forEach((image) => {
    const sliderItem = document.createElement("img");
    sliderItem.src = image.src; // this line result in 404 not found in dev tool
    ...
  })
}
...

index.js
...
initialize(
  {
    src: "image relative path here";
  }
);

im using webpack 5, i can load image by src property in html file and by url("") in css file ... but not this dynamic path in js. Can anyone tell me why and how to solve it?
i don't want to use import someimage from "some image path" because i want this to be dynamic so i can use images from database or image that user upload.

place your images in public folder in your root direcotry of your project and acces it as follows:
const initialize = (pImages) => {
  pImages.forEach((image) => {
    const sliderItem = document.createElement("img");
    sliderItem.src = `/images/${image.src}`;  
    ...
  });
};


webpack cannot automatically resolve paths that are set dynamically at runtime because these paths are not known during the build process therfore it results in 404
